# General Confusion around subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this (example)

```
table1
id | datab    | datac
1  | 5        | 10
2  | 5        | 10
3  | 9        | 10
```

and a second table, table2, where ptid is equal to id in the first

```
table2
id | ptid | dataz
1  | 1    | 99999
2  | 1    | 848483
3  | 1    | 11111
4  | 2    | 76543
```

I want to return all values from table 2 where t1.id=t2.ptid, without SQL creating an entire new row, with a duplicate t1 record for each t2, as I would get with a join.

This seems like an absolute basic SQL situation. I tried using sub select

```
SELECT t1.id,
(SELECT t2.dataz
FROM table2 AS t2
WHERE t1.id=t2.ptid
)
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE t1.id IN (1,2)
```

Right now SQL says it is errored out returning more than one row, which it is what I think I want it to do. But likely SQL does not know how to handle more than one row being returned like that (you likely cant have a row in a row). So, obviously this does not work.

What I want to see happen is that sub select query return something I can turn into an array of all values returned from that sub select, so I can pass it through PHP to javascript and use.

What I had been doing in the past is making function after function for each sub query and querying using the main query's ID, then merging the sub query results into an array which would get passed and merged into the main query to create the multidimensional array that I want. This seems inefficient and I am sure there is a more elegant solution to this issue.

What is the most efficient way of doing something like this, that actually works?

I don't know if it makes any difference but I am using PHP MySQLI and prepared statements in my non example code.

Comment: What is the result you're trying to get?

Comment: I suspect what you want is `GROUP_CONCAT(t2.dataz)`, but the question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question isn't clear, but I suspect this is what you want:

```
SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.dataz) AS dataz
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.ptid
WHERE t1.id in (1, 2)
GROUP BY t1.id
```

`GROUP_CONCAT(t2.dataz)` will create a comma-delimited string of all the `t2.dataz` values.

```
id dataz
1  99999,848483,11111
2  76543
```